# How to find TeacherId from teacher's full name

Tags: php, sql

Below I have a $_POST variable for the teacher's firstname and surname:

```
if (isset($_POST['teacherforename'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $_POST['teacherforename'];

}

if (isset($_POST['teachersurname'])) {

$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $_POST['teachersurname'];

}
```

Now the problem I have is that I want to insert this into the database but I don't want the firstname and surname to be inserted into the database, I want the teacher's username to be inserted into the database.

For example: John May has a username T1, Ben Watts has a username T2 and Jean Smart has a username T3.

So how can I get it so that it looks up the teacher's firstname and surname, find the teacher's username from that (field for username is TeacherId) and then insert the username in the 'TeacherId' field in the "Session" Table?

I have connection to database and all that. I just want to how to code it so that it finds a teacher's username (TeacherId) by its full name then insert it into the database?

Comment: What if two people have the same name???

Comment: I was just thinking how many *John smiths* are in the UK?!

Comment: Guys sorry ignore this question, I am a fool, I wasn't thinking at all. I have a login page which asks for user's teacher login details, I can use that to get teacher's userId. Sorry everybody, what a stupid question

Comment: Would it be wise for some of us to close the question?

Comment: Hi, yes please close this question if you can :) sorry about this

Answer (score 0):

Do you want Teacherid (like T1,T2,T2) by looking username which is obtained by selecting surname and forename??

```
SELECT TeacherId FROM (SELECT Username from teachers where forename='forename' and surname='surname')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not query database with WHERE `name`='$name'  (combination of firstname.' '.lastname)
 And use the returned ID in your script?